# Where should I put `mutex` in order to delete an element from a slice in Go? The parent or child struct?

Tags: go, struct, synchronization, slice, mutex

Let's say I have two structs as follows:

```
type Device struct {
     Ports []*TCPPort
}

type TCPPort struct {
     ID int
     State bool
     Device *Device
}
```

When a `TCPPort` is created, it's appended as follows:

```
// Body of the `createTCPPort is intentionally left blank. Imagine it creates a port and returns it.`
func createTCPPort() *TCPPort {}
tcp := createTCPPort()
device.Ports = append(device.Ports, tcp)
```

At any given time, one of the TCP ports is requested to be deleted. I want to delete/remove this port from this slice where I append the ports through the device. Port `Ports []*TCPPort`.  It doesn't matter I guess at the moment whether this operation will be in-order or not. I am confused where should I put `Mutex` and use the functionalities of it which are `lock` and `unlock`.

Should I place it inside the `Device` struct like the following?

```
type Device struct {
     portMutex  sync.Mutex
     Ports []*TCPPort
}

// And then remove the element as follows:?
func (d Device) removePortFromSlice(){
    d.portMutex.Lock()
    defer d.portMutex.Lock()
    // Remove slice operation here
}
```

*Or*

```
type TCPPort struct {
     PortMutex sync.Mutex
     ID int
     State bool
     Device *Device
}

func (tcp TCPPort) removeElementFromSlice() {
    tcp.portMutex.Lock()
    defer tcp.portMutex.Lock()
    // Remove operation here
}
```

Should I place the Mutex into a parent struct which is `Device` or the child struct which is `TCPPort`?

Answer (score 0):

Since the slice of ports is a field on the Device struct, it makes sense to put the mutex lock in Device to synchronize access to that specific field.

Here is a suggestion about using the mutex:

```golang
type Device struct {
  portMutex sync.Mutex
  Ports     []*TCPPort 
}

func (d *Device) RemovePort(port *TCPPort) {

  d.portMutex.Lock()
  defer d.portMutex.Unlock()

  // Find index of port to remove
  index := -1
  for i, p := range d.Ports {
    if p == port {
      index = i
      break
    }
  }

  // Remove from slice
  if index != -1 {
    d.Ports = append(d.Ports[:index], d.Ports[index+1:]...) 
  }

}
```

This locks access to the Ports slice specifically when removing an item.

Putting the mutex on TCPPort doesn't work as well because even though each TCPPort struct will be locked, the slice in Device can still be modified concurrently by other goroutines.
The key is synchronizing access to the shared data structure that needs concurrent access protection.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can use a Mutex to safely handle concurrent access to the Ports slice in the Device struct. Placing the Mutex inside the Device struct is a reasonable approach.

Here's how you can modify your Device struct and add methods to safely add and remove TCP ports using a Mutex:

```
    import "sync"

type Device struct {
    Ports []*TCPPort
    mu    sync.Mutex // Mutex to protect access to Ports
}

type TCPPort struct {
    ID     int
    State  bool
    Device *Device
}

// Method to add a TCP port to the Device's Ports slice safely
func (d *Device) AddPort(tcp *TCPPort) {
    d.mu.Lock()
    defer d.mu.Unlock()
    d.Ports = append(d.Ports, tcp)
}

// Method to remove a TCP port from the Device's Ports slice safely
func (d *Device) RemovePort(tcp *TCPPort) {
    d.mu.Lock()
    defer d.mu.Unlock()

    // Find the index of the TCP port in the Ports slice
    var index int
    for i, port := range d.Ports {
        if port == tcp {
            index = i
            break
        }
    }

    // Remove the TCP port from the slice
    d.Ports = append(d.Ports[:index], d.Ports[index+1:]...)
}
```

Now, when you want to add or remove TCP ports, you can do so using the AddPort and RemovePort methods of the Device struct, respectively. The Mutex ensures that only one goroutine can modify the Ports slice at a time, providing concurrent safety.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT